# C++ when you dereference a pointer to a class object and then return it as a reference, can you call methods on this reference

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, reference

In the code below `CompositionalModel` is an abstract class. The class `OpModel` provides implementations of the virtual functions.

In the class `CompilationUnit` there is a member variable `model` which is a pointer to an `OpModel` class.

My question is: the method `model()` dereferences the pointer and returns it as a reference of type CompositionalModel. When you dereference a pointer and return it as a reference now an object that you can call methods on?

Comment: Yes, you can. You could simply try it.

Comment: why do you think it would not be possible? What problems did you encounter? No offense, but without this information the question is rather pointless

Comment: Please, be aware, that if `model_` is not initialized in `CompilationUnit::CompilationUnit()` or stores a `nullptr` then `*model_` will return an invalid reference. Accessing this reference is undefined behavior in this case. (If you're lucky your program simply crashs and you can see in core dump/debugger where any why.) To make this clear, you could expose implementation of `CompilationUnit::CompilationUnit()` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C++ when you dereference a pointer to a class object and then return it as a reference, can you call methods on this reference

Yes, you can call member functions of a reference.

However, note that if the pointer does not point to an object (of compatible type), then indirecting (i.e. dereferencing) the pointer has undefined behaviour. In your example program, `model_` is never initialized to point to an object, so the example has UB.